# How to combine two arrays into a hive map

Tags: hive

Given two arrays:

```
select split(concat_ws(',',array('a','b'),array('c','d')),',') as keys ,
   split(concat_ws(',',array('1','2'),array('3','4')),',') as values
```

```
    keys               values
["a","b","c","d"]   ["1","2","3","4"]
```

How can these be combined into a `hive` `map`?  The typical `map` builder takes them interleaved instead:

```
map(k1,v1,k2,v2,k3,v3,...,k_n,v_n)
```